# xsl identifier to index correlation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml with a list of persons, their database ids and a list of relations between them. It looks like this:

```
<root>
  <person>
    <id>1000</id>
    <name>p1</name>
  </person>
  <person>
    <id>1001</id>
    <name>p2</name>
  </person>
  <rel>
    <personid>1001</personid>
    <personid>1000</personid>
  </rel>
</root>
```

I'd like to generate using xslt 1.0 from java, the following:

```
person 2 relates to person 1.
```

The logic is to show the index of the person based on the order it appears in the xml.

My current ideas:

- preprocessing the xml in java and send a map as param to the xsl with [person_id, person_index] and then for each relation get the person_index from person_id
- making an xpath in xsl that finds the index of a person by a given id(although I don't know to construct a xpath for that)
- preprocessing in java and construct the map, place it in a ThreadLocal variable and then from xsl calling another method that uses this ThreadLocal to get the person index from person id

Any other ideas, hopefully more simple are very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but you might consider using attributes for single data fields. For example, you might instead have <person id="1000" name="p1"/>. Much easier to read and also easier to parse with SAX.

Comment: Thanks, I actually don't control the xml structute, it com from a different application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Java preprocessing or mapping is necessary.

```
<xsl:key name="kPersonById" match="person" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="rel">
  <xsl:text>Person </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="key('kPersonById', personid[1])/name" />
  <xsl:text> relates to </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="key('kPersonById', personid[2])/name" />
  <xsl:text>.&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This would generate one line of text for every `<rel>` there is. It's not a complete stylesheet, I'll leave figuring out the rest to you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but person 1 means the person with the xml order 1. I don't want to use the name tag value(p1). Is it possible?

Comment: @dan: Yes, of course. Use `"key(...)/count(preceding-sibling::person) + 1"`

Comment: This seems to be the nice and simple way to do it. I appreciate your quick response.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there must be a better way but this works:

Replying to good advice from Dimitre - Please note that this solution relies on being able to use XLST 2.0. In XLST 1.0 variables are "result tree fragments" and you cant then use them and add xpaths to them without using extensions such as saxon:parse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">

<xsl:variable name="indexed">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/person"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/rel"/>           
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/person">
    <xsl:copy>
        <index>
            <!-- concern - will this make the approach take O(n^2) and 
                 therefore get very slow for large input docs -->
            <xsl:number/>
        </index>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/rel">
    <xsl:variable name="p1" select="personid[1]/text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="p2" select="personid[2]/text()"/>
    <xsl:text>Person </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indexed/person[id = $p1]/index"/>
    <xsl:text> relates to person </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indexed/person[id = $p2]/index"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please, mention in this answer that this is an XSLT 2.0 solution -- otherwise very few (if any) people will notice this significant fact. Because you are using almost nothing from XSLT 2.0, why not try to produce an XSLT 1.0 solution (or a true XSLT 2.0 solution)? Finally, this solution may be slow for a large number of `person` and `rel` elements.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation** (works with relations with two or more persons):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPersonById" match="person" use="id"/>

 <xsl:template match="rel/personid">
  <xsl:variable name="vPersInd" select=
   "count(key('kPersonById', .)
           /preceding-sibling::person
         )
          +1 "/>
   <xsl:text> is related to  person </xsl:text>

  <xsl:value-of select="$vPersInd"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="rel/personid[1]">
  <xsl:variable name="vPersInd" select=
   "count(key('kPersonById', .)
           /preceding-sibling::person
         )
          +1 "/>
  person <xsl:value-of select="$vPersInd"/><xsl:text/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (added a third person to make it more interesting)

```
<root>
    <person>
        <id>1000</id>
        <name>p1</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>1001</id>
        <name>p2</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>1002</id>
        <name>p3</name>
    </person>
    <rel>
        <personid>1001</personid>
        <personid>1000</personid>
        <personid>1002</personid>
    </rel>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
  person 2 is related to  person 1 is related to  person 3
```

Comment: When I, eventually, understood what you were doing here Dimitre, I burst out laughing - very clever - It is not obvious to a novice how this works though - I am sure you can explain your solution much better than I could

Comment: Very clever indeed and a nice way to solve relations with many elements. However I'm not sure what the last template with match=text() does. Thanks!

Comment: @dan leadgy: The template `<xsl:template match="text()"/>` eliminates any text node in the document from being output -- which would otherwise happen, due to the XSLT processing model -- using XSLT built-in templates results in outputting all text nodes in the XSLT document.